# What part number is this? - 1 x 1 at a right angle with one stud and one hole

Tags: part-identification

My son needs this part and I'm unable to find its part number. Can anyone  identify it?

[image: 1 x 1 at a right angle with one stud and one hole]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The black part is:

[Part# 42446 : Minifigure Neck Bracket with Back Stud - Thin Back Wall](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42446#T=C)

or

[Part# 28974 : Minifigure Neck Bracket with Back Stud - Thick Back Wall](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28974#T=C)